# Auto-Renewable Subscription not visible in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to create a new InApp Purchases product in iTunes Connect but I don't see the Auto-Renewable Subscription type.

I currently have a Technical role. **Do I need the Admin role to create this type of product ?**

I can't see any other explanation on why this kind of product is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a legal issue.
Ask your team-agent or an iTunes User with de "Legal" role to check if all the in app purchase contracts have been accepted.